# Object positioning is off

Tags: swift, object, sprite-kit, swift2

[image: my game scene]

Hi, I’m trying to get an object (in this case a green frog) to spawn in line with the player sprite (the red frog) on a platform which is as wide as the scene and what i mean by this, is getting the object to spawn so that when the player advances it doesn’t overlap the object. (The picture shows how the green frog is between two red frogs and not in line with one of the red frogs)

My code for positioning of the objects is as follows

```
obstacle.position = CGPointMake(-(backgroundSprite.size.width / 2) + CGFloat(randomX) + (spacing * CGFloat(i)), 0)
```

this currently spawns it on the left side the screen half off the scene. the background sprite is what the object is being added to which is defined like so:

```
let theSize:CGSize = CGSizeMake(levelUnitWidth, levelUnitHeight)       
let tex:SKTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: imageName)          
backgroundSprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: tex, color: SKColor.blackColor(), size: theSize)
```

random x is also what spawns them randomly on the x axis of the background sprite (which I have also tried adjusting with no luck)

```
let randomX = arc4random_uniform(  UInt32 (backgroundSprite.size.height) )
```

lastly spacing is the distance between the objects in the same level unit.

```
let spacing:CGFloat = 250
```

I have tried implementing the player sprites width as a reference and is hasn’t worked. Can some please tell me what i’m doing wrong here.

Here is the full code if you need to look at it all:

```
if (theType == LevelType.road) {

for (var i = 0; i < Int(numberOfObjectsInLevel); i++) {

     let obstacle:Object = Object()


     obstacle.theType = LevelType.road


     obstacle.createObject()
     addChild(obstacle)


     let spacing:CGFloat = 250
     obstacle.position = CGPointMake((backgroundSprite.size.width / 4) + CGFloat(randomX) + (spacing * CGFloat(i)), 0)

    }
```

**EDIT:**

I have tried implementing that code you made in your edit post with code I had already and this is what I got.

```
  if (theType == LevelType.road) {


        let xAxisSpawnLocations: [CGFloat] = {

            var spawnLocations:[CGFloat] = []

            //Create 5 possible spawn locations
            let numberOfNodes = 5

            for i in 0...numberOfNodes - 1 {

                /*
                Spacing between nodes will change if:

                1) number of nodes is changed,
                2) screen width is changed,
                3) node's size is changed.
                */

                var xPosition = (frame.maxX - thePlayer.size.width) / CGFloat((numberOfNodes - 1)) * CGFloat(i)

                //add a half of a player's width because node's anchor point is (0.5, 0.5) by default
                xPosition += thePlayer.size.width/2.0

                spawnLocations.append( xPosition )
            }

            return spawnLocations
        }()

        print(xAxisSpawnLocations)

        let yAxisSpawnLocations: [CGFloat] = [0]

        let obstacle:Object = Object()

        obstacle.theType = LevelType.road


        obstacle.createObject()
        addChild(obstacle)

        let randx = xAxisSpawnLocations[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(xAxisSpawnLocations.count)))]

        obstacle.position = CGPoint(x: randx, y: yAxisSpawnLocations[0] )
        obstacle.zPosition = 200

    }
```

**EDIT 2:**

so implemented the code again this time the right way and I got this:

[image: The second time]

So the player still isn't in line with the objects and for some reason it only spawns on the right side of the screen. I think it is because I have a worldNode that holds everything.

the worldNode holds the player which has a starting point of (0,0) in the worldNode and it also holds the level units which holds the objects. the camera position is centered on the player node I'm not sure if this is the problem but i'll provide the code below so you can have a look at it.

```
let startingPosition:CGPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
```

**The woldNode Code:**

```
let worldNode:SKNode = SKNode()


//creates the world node point to be in the middle of the screen
self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
addChild(worldNode)

//adds the player as a child node to the world node 
worldNode.addChild(thePlayer)
thePlayer.position = startingPosition
thePlayer.zPosition = 500
```

**The camera positioning code:**

```
 override func didSimulatePhysics() {

    self.centerOnNode(thePlayer) 
}

//centers the camera on the node world.
func centerOnNode(node:SKNode) {

    let cameraPositionInScene:CGPoint = self.convertPoint(node.position, fromNode: worldNode)
    worldNode.position = CGPoint(x: worldNode.position.x , y:worldNode.position.y - cameraPositionInScene.y  )

}
```

I pretty sure this is my problem but tell me what you think.

Comment: If you want green frogs in a line with red frogs, don't randomize green frogs x position. Use predefined positions (eg. fill an array with possible spawning locations )

Comment: do you have an example of how to do this (a link or something to a tutorial?)

Comment: I can write an example for you but it is the same thing as when you were adding red frogs to the screen. Just use same x position and different y position. If you still having problems, let me know.

Comment: The red frogs are photoshopped in to better illustrate the problem. if you could provide an example I would be extremely grateful. thanks for the reply.

Comment: You mean all (red) frogs are placed in a single texture ?

Comment: I mean there is only supposed to be one red frog which represents the player, I just edited in the other red frogs to better show how the green frogs are not in line with the red frog's movements.

Comment: Okay, I get it. You'll get my answer soon.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in comments, the key is to predefine coordinates for x (and y) axis and spawn nodes based on that. First, let's define a player inside your GameScene class:

```
 let player = SKSpriteNode(color: .redColor(), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
```

Now, predefine spawn locations (for both x and y axis):

```
let xAxisSpawnLocations: [CGFloat] = [50.0, 125.0, 200.0, 275.0, 350.0, 425.0]
let yAxisSpawnLocations: [CGFloat] = [50.0, 125.0,  200.0, 275.0]
```

Now when we know possible positions, let position our player first and add it to the scene:

```
player.position = CGPoint(x: xAxisSpawnLocations[0], y: yAxisSpawnLocations[0])
player.zPosition = 10
addChild(player)
```

You could create those positions based on player's width and height and screen's size, but because of simplicity, I've hardcoded everything.

So, lets fill one row, right above the player with green frogs:

```
for xLocation in xAxisSpawnLocations {

     let greenFrog = SKSpriteNode(color: .greenColor(), size: player.size)
     greenFrog.position = CGPoint(x: xLocation, y: yAxisSpawnLocations[1])
      addChild(greenFrog)
}
```

The result would be something like this:

[image]

Or, for example, move the player by one place to the right, and make a column of green frogs right above him:

```
player.position = CGPoint(x: xAxisSpawnLocations[1], y: yAxisSpawnLocations[0])


 for yLocation in yAxisSpawnLocations {

      let greenFrog = SKSpriteNode(color: .greenColor(), size: player.size)
       greenFrog.position = CGPoint(x: xAxisSpawnLocations[1], y: yLocation)
      addChild(greenFrog)
  }
```

And it should look like this:

[image]

**EDIT:**

Based on your comments, this is how you could distribute nodes across the screen based on number of nodes, screen width and node's size:

```
let xAxisSpawnLocations: [CGFloat] = {

    var spawnLocations:[CGFloat] = []

    //Create 5 possible spawn locations
    let numberOfNodes = 5

    for i in 0...numberOfNodes - 1 {

        /*
            Spacing between nodes will change if:

            1) number of nodes is changed,
            2) screen width is changed,
            3) node's size is changed.
        */

        var xPosition = (frame.maxX - player.size.width) / CGFloat((numberOfNodes - 1)) * CGFloat(i)

        //add a half of a player's width because node's anchor point is (0.5, 0.5) by default
        xPosition += player.size.width/2.0

        spawnLocations.append( xPosition )
    }

    return spawnLocations
}()

print(xAxisSpawnLocations)
```

You should handle what is happening when too much nodes are added, or if nodes are too big, but this can give you a basic idea how to distribute nodes along x axis and preserve the same distance between them.

Comment: that worked. but could you provide the example on how I would create the positions based on the player's width, height and the screen size because what you have provided me works but doesn't really fix my problem completely because of the ever changing positions because of the screen size or player sprite.

Comment: I tried implementing the edit you provided but now it takes me back to my original problem which was the player is not in line with the other green frogs. I have updated my post with my new code that I have so you can look at it. @Whirlwind

Comment: @Astrum Are you sure it doesn't work ? Create blank project, set scene to have the same size as view (`scene.size = skView.bounds.size`), set scene scale mode to .aspectFill, define player like I did, define yAxisSpawnLocations like I did, define xAxisSpawnLocations like from my edit, and use one of the `for` in loops I've provided. It will work. It works for me, and you should look into other parts of your code. So, check instances of your `Object` type, print everything (node sizes, positions, scene  size, view size etc) and find what is causing the issues.

Comment: So your example works fine, I tried it in a new game scene and it worked a treat, but the only problem is that it still doesn’t work completely on my project. I also forgot to mention that the objects are contained within a worldNode that has a camera node positioned on the player node which I believe is the reason (I couldn’t find any other reasons.) i have updated my post with another edit so you can look at it.

Comment: @Astrum Well, the whole point of my answer was to give you a basic idea of how you can use predefined coordinates to position the nodes. I believe that part is solved. If you are experiencing further issues, please try to isolate the responsible code and ask a new question.

Comment: so I tried isolating what was wrong with the code and concluded that it is in fact it is the worldNode that is making it only spawn on one side so i asked a new question because I have had no luck trying to fix it. If you could take a look at it, I would be very grateful thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35305497/worldnode-conflicting-with-object-spawning